# Difference between the results from _get_collection().find and objects() in pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am using pymongo to query mongodb. I have collection named **alph_var** and a document in this collection looks like this: `{'a':'1','c':None,'d':'1sfa','e':None}`

If I am doing `alph_var._get_collection().find({'a':'1'})`, I am getting following result:

```
{'_id':ObjectId('1242as223'),'a':'1','d':'1sfa'}
```

and when I am doing `alph_var.objects(a='1')[0]._data`, I am getting following result:

```
{'id':ObjectId('1242as223'), 'a':'1','c':None,'d':'1sfa','e':None}
```

I am completely new to pymongo, any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Why are you calling _get_collection?

Comment: I thought it also results in the same way as objects()

Comment: Well I think gecollection ignores the None values while objects doesn't. What don't you understand?

Comment: I am not able to understand why _get_collection is ignoring None values? shouldn't it be giving the complete document?

Comment: Why would you insert a None value in the first place?

Comment: This data is loaded into mongodb. I have to use this data for further computations. For the further computations, I have put checks whether 'c' or 'e' is none or not. Since these keys are ignored, my code is breaking. I know I can use the objects(). It is just that I want to understand why these none values are ignored.

Comment: You kan check whether a key is pressent in a dictionary with "if key in dict:". BTW Who loaded that data into mongo and how. I don't recommend using None values in Mongodb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you're using MongoEngine, a wrapper ("Object Document Mapper") around PyMongo. When you call _get_collection and get a handle to the underlying PyMongo Collection instance, and query it, you get a raw representation of the BSON documents in MongoDB with no further processing. Evidently this particular document only has fields "_id", "a", and "d". It does not contain fields "c" and "e" at all. (MongoDB documents can include or omit any field but "_id".)

When you use MongoEngine, however, it enforces a schema on your documents. I think you've defined fields "c" and "e" in your MongoEngine schema. So when MongoEngine retrieves the document, it sees that the document lacks "c" and "e", so it sets them to None in its internal "_data" dict.

Comment: Thank you for the clarity. Now I understand why this is happening :) Yes, in my MongoEngine, I am enforcing a schema on my documents. A quick question - Is it a good practice to enforce Schema in MongoEngine?